# gStreamer: Create RTSP stream using jpeg images from a RAM partition

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp

Objective:
To create an RTSP stream (h264 or h265) using gStreamer from a single image which is being continuously overwritten. (This image is coming from an API on to a shared memory partition)

Problems:
Have been able to make a video stream over RTSP using gStreamer (gst-launch-1.0) but have had zero luck with these images, tried multifilesrc and other options but ran out of luck.
Also, I tried FFmpeg where the its probably point-to-point only, which is not what I need.

Any suggestions/help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic for a few reason.  How would one know when the file was updated?  Each time you read (and write!) the data, even just the timestamp, you are IO blocking -- either blocking the read operation, or preventing it from writing.  Or what if the data's timestamp change was quicker than a second? It might just hang even though the data changed.  Oof.  This I/O blocking activity is like an eternity to a CPU, even if it's a VERY fast SSD (they too have to "seek" even if its in microseconds, and checkout their write speeds -- they often differ, a lot).

How might one expect to do this in "real time," especially if the time between reads (and writes!) vary.  These operations will cause frame skipping for the reasons above.

I don't know the specifics of gStreamer (at all) or your setup, but I would suggest piping the file over STDIN/STDOUT.  In this way, the data doesn't move, it is only updated, often in-place.  Instead your giving the application(s) a single number: An address.  A signal (*flush* baby, *flush*) is given to read it again and again and again.  Millions if not Billions of times faster.  This is make the process CPU bound.  Your process will get it's own thread too.